# CoreData fetch adding an attribute based on a predicate

Tags: ios, core-data

I have the following data model (simplified):

```
WordEntity          ListItemEntity          ListEntity
----------          --------------          ----------
text                                        name
----------          --------------          ----------
listItems <------>> word
                    list <<---------------> items
```

And the following basic query:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "WordEntity")
let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

let list = <ListEntity instance>
... do something clever here ...
controller.performFetch(nil)
```

I need the fetched results to include an attribute `inList` for each object, which would be true if that WordEntity object is attached to a ListItemEntity which is in turn attached to `list`. Something like the following predicate, except used to create a new attribute instead of filtering the fetch request:

```
NSPredicate(format: "ANY listItems.list == %@", list)
```

I looked at NSExpressions but they seem to only be used to aggregate, and can't do predicates. SUBQUERY can do predicates but only for filtering the result set. And calculated transient attributes can do any lookups I want, but there is no way for them to operate on an external value...

I hope this is clear... thanks in advance.

## Update:

I was able to do this using fetched properties, as pbasdf suggested. I have a fetched property `listItemsInList` on `WordEntity` with predicate:

```
(word == $FETCH_SOURCE) AND (list == $FETCHED_PROPERTY.userInfo.list)
```

Then in code:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest()
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("WordEntity", inManagedObjectContext: context)!
request.entity = entity
for property in entity.properties {
    if property.name == "listItemsInList" {
        let list = <ListEntity instance>
        (property as NSFetchedPropertyDescription).userInfo!["list"] = list
    }
}
```

And finally:

```
if word.listItemsInList.count > 0 {
    ... this is what I was looking for ...
}
```

This works. Unfortunately it's very inefficient. Fetched properties always return arrays of fetched objects, not calculated values. They always fetch the whole object. And worst of all, they can't be pre-fetched, so checking the property in a table cell means a database hit for every row. So I'm still hoping there's a smarter way to do it.

Comment: Have you looked into Fetched Properties?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think it was doable with fetched properties, but I tried again on your suggestion and I got it to work. I've updated the question with details.

Comment: If you are just looking to check whether a given word is in a given list, try `if ([word.listItems intersectsSet:list.items]) { ...}` (sorry, Objective-C).

Comment: Thanks. It's ok, I can read Objective-C. I did it this way at first, just checking the set, but I thought there should be a better way to do it. I think that if I can get it into the same CoreData query that fetches the word list it would be the most efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error, I have found a solution which will achieve what you want with a single CoreData fetch, provided you are happy with the entity's attributes being returned "by value" (i.e. they will be copies of the underlying attributes) in an array of dictionaries.  The one saving grace is that the dictionary can include the CoreData objectID of the relevant object, so it is relatively straight forward to retrieve that object.

The trick is to use an NSExpression which includes a SUBQUERY (with the relevant list name substituted in) and @count.  Here's what I used (sorry, Obj-C again!):

```
// First, get an NSAttribute description for each of the attributes we want in our query
NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"WordEntity" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
NSAttributeDescription *wordDesc = [entity.attributesByName objectForKey:@"word"];

// Also get an NSExpression description for the object itself
NSExpression *objIDExpression = [NSExpression expressionForEvaluatedObject];
NSExpressionDescription *objIDDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[objIDDescription setName: @"cdObjectID"];
[objIDDescription setExpression: objIDExpression];
[objIDDescription setExpressionResultType: NSObjectIDAttributeType];

// Define an expression to count a subquery
NSExpression *countExpression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(listItems,$x,$x.list.listName like %@).@count",@"Animals",nil]; 
// Note, in the above, replace @"Animals" with list.listName for the list of interest

NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[expressionDescription setName: @"count"];
[expressionDescription setExpression: countExpression];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType: NSInteger32AttributeType];

NSFetchRequest* fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"WordEntity"];
[fetch setPropertiesToFetch:@[wordDesc, objIDDescription, expressionDescription]];
[fetch setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
NSArray *myResults = [self.context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
NSLog(@"myResults: %@",myResults);
// Recover the actual WordEntity object for the first item in myResults:
WordEntity *myWord = (WordEntity *)[self.context objectWithID:[[myResults firstObject] valueForKey:@"cdObjectID"]];
```

The output for myResults looks like this.  My test data included various words which I included in lists named Animals, Food, etc.  The output below is for Animals; note count=1 for Dog!

```
    {
    cdObjectID = "0xd000000000040004 <x-coredata://4B6BC796-CAEF-4B0C-9B27-BC6CCDA572C7/WordEntity/p1>";
    count = 0;
    word = Orange;
},
    {
    cdObjectID = "0xd000000000080004 <x-coredata://4B6BC796-CAEF-4B0C-9B27-BC6CCDA572C7/WordEntity/p2>";
    count = 0;
    word = Geranium;
},
    {
    cdObjectID = "0xd0000000000c0004 <x-coredata://4B6BC796-CAEF-4B0C-9B27-BC6CCDA572C7/WordEntity/p3>";
    count = 0;
    word = Banana;
},
    {
    cdObjectID = "0xd000000000100004 <x-coredata://4B6BC796-CAEF-4B0C-9B27-BC6CCDA572C7/WordEntity/p4>";
    count = 1;
    word = Dog;
},
    {
    cdObjectID = "0xd000000000140004 <x-coredata://4B6BC796-CAEF-4B0C-9B27-BC6CCDA572C7/WordEntity/p5>";
    count = 0;
    word = Apple;
},
    {
    cdObjectID = "0xd000000000180004 <x-coredata://4B6BC796-CAEF-4B0C-9B27-BC6CCDA572C7/WordEntity/p6>";
    count = 1;
    word = Elephant;
}, ....
```

I've no idea how that will compare performance-wise with the other solutions!

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the kind of thing I was hoping to be able to do.